# KDE5 System tray icons not activating windows

Tags: kubuntu, system-tray

I can't get tray icons to activate windows, for example I have: Skype, Viber, Chrome, Thunderbird and click on any of these doesn't show up anything. I have to do right click and then depending on the app click "Open Skype" for example to bring it on focus. Kubuntu 16.04.1 with KDE Frameworks 5.28.0, Qt 5.6.1 (built against 5.6.1). Any suggestions?

[System tray icons screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSQzL.png)

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot Nick?

Comment: There is a screenshot attached in original post https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSQzL.png